# creating a matrix with randomly generated numbers

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

```
import random
def list_2d_generate(rows, columns, low_range, high_range):
    float_list = []
    matrix1 = [[0]*columns for i in range(rows)]
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):
            floats = random.uniform(low_range, high_range)
            matrix1.insert(j, floats)
    return matrix1
```

I'm supposed to create a matrix with size determined by the user, and for each element in that matrix generate a random float using random.uniform. Above is my code, but it puts all the numbers generated outside the matrix (adds them to the list instead of inside the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

```
import random
def makematrix(x,y,minnum, maxnum):
    matrix = []
    for row in range(x):
        matrix.append([])
        for col in range(y):
            matrix[row].append(random.uniform(minnum,maxnum))
    return matrix

print(makematrix(4,4,0,100))
```

sample output:

```
[[44.75502455476652, 28.664480955351777, 32.656439723011175, 3.9675096554774303] [61.990473239473566, 55.16751027710425, 62.20529230301345, 53.641004392485584], [1.4753516149572543, 8.391386895268615, 61.87234529817771, 11.364854440314732], [21.122758368045947, 62.155653114217145, 85.20532313391281, 97.60326478339135]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to format the output to actually look like a matrix and without [] brackets?

Comment: you can loop through the matrix with a pair of `for` loops, and format it however you please. This is just the default format when printing a list

Answer (score 1):

List insert adds values rather than replacing existing values.

Instead of generating the matrix and then filling it, generate it with the values:

```
import random
def list_2d_generate(rows, columns, low_range, high_range):
  return [
    [random.uniform(low_range, high_range)
      for _ in xrange(columns)]
    for _ in xrange(rows)]
```